# Integrate Ruby-Lint with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, static-analysis, lint

I have a Rails 4.2 project that uses Bundler and Rspec. I want ruby-lint to work with my specs. By default it doesn't:

```
$ ruby-lint spec/models/user_spec.rb 
user_spec.rb: error: line 3, column 1: undefined constant RSpec
user_spec.rb: error: line 4, column 3: undefined method describe
user_spec.rb: error: line 5, column 5: undefined method let
```

I have `require 'rails_helper'` in `spec/models/user_spec.rb` so it is natural to expect that `ruby-lint` would load it and therefore load `rspec`.

What should I do in order to make ruby-lint handle spec files correctly?

P.S. I don't have any specific ruby-lint configuration.

P.P.S. I have the same question for the `Gemfile` file.

P.P.P.S. Actually I need it in order to get error checking in vim via synstastic or neomake.

Answer (score 1):

I have only used ruby-lint sparingly (because of the many false negatives it gives). So I am no expert unfortunately.

I suppose you want to use it in some automated way, because from the command line you can just point it to the directory that you need.

Looking at the code you can put the directories that you want to lint in a config file. I think something like the following entry should work:

```
directories: ['lib']
```

See [example config.yaml](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/blob/master/spec/fixtures/config.yml) and [example rspecs](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/blob/master/spec/ruby-lint/configuration_spec.rb) and of course the [relevant config code](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/blob/master/lib/ruby-lint/configuration.rb).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. But I thought that a lot of people use ruby-lint together with Rails and Rspec or at least with Bundler and there is some config options for it.

Comment: I think most people use [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) for that purpose.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. But I think it is reasonable to have some clear view on the subject.

Comment: We indeed use Rubocop. It works ok. I do not want to imply that it is better than ruby-lint, because I would have to use it first. Not enough experience with it.